# By default show chapters when embedding video on SharePoint page?

Tags: video

When embedding a sharepoint video in a site. Is it possible to have the chapters by default visible (opened)for users?

Currently users first have to press the chapter icon in the top right corner of the video to show the chapters.

[image]

```
<iframe src="https://tennant.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/_layouts/15/embed.aspx?UniqueId=83474249-2ad7-4416-bd6f-4e83bdf31690&amp;embed=%7B%22ust%22%3Atrue%2C%22hv%22%3A%22CopyEmbedCode%22%7D&amp;referrer=StreamWebApp&amp;referrerScenario=EmbedDialog.Create" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" title="Something.mp4"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't think there are any settings for showing chapters by default while embedding a video in SharePoint page.